# What is a good CSS style to represent "loading . . ."?

Tags: html, css, ajax, row, css-tables

I have been using blockUI which works great but I need to dynamically load a table row and from research it seems like blockUI doesn't work with HTML table rows.

I was just thinking of using:

`jquery.AddClass("highlightCell")` to start loading and `jquery.RemoveClass()` when the AJAX call returns.

Here is my current CSS but it doesn't look quite right so wanted to get some feedback or suggestions to show that a HTML table row is being "refreshed"

```
.highlightCell {
  background-color: #767070;
  -moz-opacity: 0.60;
  opacity: .60;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually make one of [this](http://www.ajaxload.info/) in an appropiate color and center them as background-image.